# Recent documents list gets cleared after app relaunch

Tags: cocoa, nsdocumentcontroller, recent-documents

I have a non-document-based application in which I would like to use the "Open Recent" menu item to open a recently opened item. I've implemented this using `application:openFile:` and `noteNewRecentDocumentURL:` as described [here](http://www.buckleyisms.com/home/2008/10/22/using-the-open-recent-menu-in-cocoa-without-nsdocument.html).

**AppDelegate.m** *(excerpt)*

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFile:(NSString *)filename {
    [self.someController openRecentDocument:filename];
    return YES;
}
```

**SomeController.m** *(excerpt)*

```
[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] noteNewRecentDocumentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
```

This seems to partially work initially, with the document appearing in the menu after calling `noteNewRecentDocumentURL:` but after relaunching the app, the "Open Recent" menu is empty.

Is there something else I need to do to get this to work properly?

Comment: Did you use the stop button from Xcode ? I noticed that I have to close application properly to save the opened file entries in the menu.

Comment: I didn't use the stop button (I used Cmd-Q), but running the application as a normal executable outside of Xcode seems to have fixed the problem. If you'd like to put that as an answer I'll happily accept it.